# VOIP in Android..?

Tags: android, sip, voip, sip-server, sipdroid

I am developing an app where i need to implement VOIP in that. I have gone through some samples in google like [SIPDROID](http://www.voipvoip.com/sipdroid/), IMSDROID and implemented default android API [SIP](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html). They are working good. But here I want to interrupt the message while transferring i mean while 1 user says "Hi" i want to encrypt the following message and need to send the encrypted message to other user & at the other end i want to decrypt that message. So any one can help me how to interrupt the message while sending & do my process.... ?

Comment: Surely this would depend on which of those libraries you are using?

Comment: actually i am following SIPDROID source code. can you help me with this..?

Comment: when compare with sipdroid,imsdroid etc..which one is better to use.i get so confused.i going to develop voip application.can u give any suggestion.@code_finder